# PHP/CodeIgniter file url - Forbidden Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am a PHP/CodeIgniter newbie and am asking for some guidance on file structure.
Here is what's happening --> When I try to access a file (mp4 or pdf) by just entering the url into the address bar for my localhost, I am receiving a "Forbidden error" -- but no error when I access a jpeg file in the same directory.

Works:

```
http://localhost:8888/uploads/test-image.jpeg
```

Forbidden Error in same directory:

```
http://localhost:8888/uploads/_intro.mp4
http://localhost:8888/uploads/test.pdf
```

Although this does work for the mp4 and pdf file:

```
file:///Users/mattellis/_projects/test-projects/test/web/uploads/_intro.mp4
file:///Users/mattellis/_projects/test-projects/test/web/uploads/_intro.mp4
```

I need to be able access the mp4 and pdf files for the application, but not sure why the error  - any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

.htaccess file in web folder:

```
#Header set X-Robots-Tag "index"

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wheelbalancetraining.com$
#RewriteRule (.*) http://wheelbalancetraining.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|wp|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

php_value max_input_time 600
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
```

.htaccess file in uploads folder:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the file permission on your files `/uploads/_intro.mp4` and
`/uploads/test.pdf`, they should be readable by your web server in order to be served as web files.

your try running this on command line:

```
$ cd /Users/mattellis/_projects/test-projects/test/web
$ chmod +r ./uploads/*
```

UPDATE:

if above didnt work, update the `/Users/mattellis/_projects/test-projects/test/web/uploads/.htaccess` file to:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(jpe?g|png|gif|mp4|pdf)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: ran that command in the web directory  -but still getting the forbidden error

Comment: do you have `/Users/mattellis/_projects/test-projects/test/web/.htaccess` file, if so, what is the contents?

Comment: just added htaccess file  --> looks like there was one in the uploads folder as well

Comment: bubjavier your comment led to the answer  ...changing the .htaccess file to "<Files ~ ".(jpe?g|png|gif|mp4|pdf)$">"  --If you add that to your answer, I will mark it as correct

Comment: looks like the .htaccess in your uploads folder is the one denying access from your .mp4 and .pdf files, try to add .pdf and .mp4 on them: